# how to validate form and sending email

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, vbscript

i have one form that validate form fields with javascript and sending email with VBscript. how ever validation works fine but email not sent to email account.

VBScript to sending email:

```
<%
posted = request.form ("submit")
if posted = "Submit" then

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'' Customize the following 5 lines with your own information. ''
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
vtoaddress =   "___________" ' Change this to the email address you will be receiving your notices.
vmailhost =    "smtp.gmail.com" ' Change this to your actual Domain name.
vfromaddress = "___________" ' Change this to the email address you will use to send and authenticate with.
vfrompwd =     "___________" ' Change this to the above email addresses password.

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'' DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING PAST THIS LINE ''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
vsubject =  request.form ("subject")   
vfromname = request.form ("fname")
vbody = request.form ("message")
vrplyto = request.form ("email")
vrcity = request.form ("city")
vrmono = request.form ("phone")
vmsgbody = "<b>Name:</b> "& vfromname & "<br><b>Email:</b> "& vrplyto &"<br><b>Mobile No:</b> "& vrmono &"<br><b>City:</b> "& vrcity &"<br><b>Subject:</b> "& vsubject&"<br><b>Message:</b> "& vbody

Set objEmail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")

objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = vmailhost
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = 1
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = vfromaddress
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = vfrompwd
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Update

objEmail.Subject = vsubject
objEmail.From = vfromaddress
objEmail.To=vfromaddress
objEmail.HTMLBody = vmsgbody
objEmail.Send
    vErr = Err.Description
    if vErr <> "" then
        response.write vErr & "<br><br>There was an error on this page."
        'MsgBox("There was an error on this page.")
    else
        response.write "Thank you, your message has been sent."
        'MsgBox("Thank you, your message has been sent.")
    End If
Set objEmail = Nothing
response.write "Thank you, your message has been sent."
'MsgBox("Thank you, your message has been sent.")
end if
%>
```

Javascript to validate form:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
    function validate()
    {
        var count_bug=0;    
        if(document.form1.fname.value=="")
        {
            document.getElementById("alertMsgfname").innerHTML="&nbsp;Enter Your First Name.&nbsp;";
            document.getElementById("alertMsgfname").style.visibility="visible";
            if(eval(count_bug)==0) 
                document.form1.fname.focus();
            count_bug+=1;
        }
        if(document.form1.email.value=="")
        {
            document.getElementById("alertMsgemail").innerHTML="&nbsp;Enter Your E-mail.&nbsp;";
            document.getElementById("alertMsgemail").style.visibility="visible";
            if(eval(count_bug)==0) 
                document.form1.email.focus();
            count_bug+=1;
        }
        else if(!isEmail(document.form1.email.value))
            {    
            document.getElementById("alertMsgemail").innerHTML="&nbsp;Enter Valid E-mail!&nbsp;";
            document.getElementById("alertMsgemail").style.visibility="visible";
            if(eval(count_bug)==0) 
                document.form1.email.focus();
            count_bug+=1; 
            }
        if(document.form1.phone.value=="")
        {
            document.getElementById("alertMsgphone").innerHTML="&nbsp;Your Phone No.&nbsp;";
            document.getElementById("alertMsgphone").style.visibility="visible";
            if(eval(count_bug)==0) 
                document.form1.phone.focus();
            count_bug+=1;
        }

        else if(!ValidateNo(document.form1.phone.value," 1234567890,-/+"))
        {
            document.getElementById("alertMsgphone").innerHTML="&nbsp;Invalid Phone No.&nbsp;";
            document.getElementById("alertMsgphone").style.visibility="visible";
            if(eval(count_bug)==0) 
                document.form1.phone.focus();
            count_bug+=1;
        }
        else if(document.form1.phone.value.length < 5)
        {
            document.getElementById("alertMsgphone").innerHTML="&nbsp;Invalid Phone No.&nbsp;";
            document.getElementById("alertMsgphone").style.visibility="visible";
            if(eval(count_bug)==0) 
                document.form1.phone.focus();
            count_bug+=1;
        }
        if(document.form1.city.value=="")
        {
            document.getElementById("alertMsgCity").innerHTML="&nbsp;Enter Your City Name.&nbsp;";
            document.getElementById("alertMsgCity").style.visibility="visible";
            if(eval(count_bug)==0) 
                document.form1.city.focus();
            count_bug+=1;
        }
        if(document.form1.subject.value=="")
        {
            document.getElementById("alertMsgSubject").innerHTML="&nbsp;Enter Your Subject.&nbsp;";
            document.getElementById("alertMsgSubject").style.visibility="visible";
            if(eval(count_bug)==0) 
                document.form1.subject.focus();
            count_bug+=1;
        }
        if(document.form1.message.value=="")
        {
            document.getElementById("alertMsgMessage").innerHTML="&nbsp;Enter Your Message.&nbsp;";
            document.getElementById("alertMsgMessage").style.visibility="visible";
            if(eval(count_bug)==0) 
                document.form1.message.focus();
            count_bug+=1;
        }
    if(count_bug>0)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
    }
function isEmail (emailIn){
    var isEmailOk = false;
    var filter = /^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9._-]*\@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z-]+)+$/
    //  var filter = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\”]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\”]+)*)|(\”.+\”))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/

    if(emailIn.search(filter) != -1)
        isEmailOk = true;
    if(emailIn.indexOf("..") != -1)
        isEmailOk = false;
    if(emailIn.indexOf(".@") != -1)
        isEmailOk = false;

    return isEmailOk;
}
function ValidateNo( NumStr, String )
{
    for( var Idx = 0; Idx < NumStr.length; Idx ++ )
    {
        var Char = NumStr.charAt( Idx );
        var Match = false;
        for( var Idx1 = 0; Idx1 < String.length; Idx1 ++)
        {
            if( Char == String.charAt( Idx1 ) )
            Match = true;
        }
        if ( !Match )
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
    </script>
```

html form code:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();"> 
          <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="table-format">
          <tr valign="middle">
            <td align="left" class="text-fm" width="23%" style="padding-top:8px;">
             <b>Name<font color="#C70017">*</font></b></td>
            <td align="left" class="text-fm" width="5%">
            <b>:</b></td>
            <td class="text-fm" align="left"> 
              <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" size="43" maxlength="40" class="inp">
              <span id="alertMsgfname" class="valfrm" style='line-height:8px;'></span></td>
          </tr>
         <tr valign="middle">
            <td align="left" class="text-fm" style="padding-top:8px;">
             <b>Email Id<font color="#C70017">*</font></b></td>
            <td align="left" class="text-fm">
            <b>:</b></td>
            <td class="text-fm" align="left"> 
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="43" maxlength="76" class="inp">
            <span id="alertMsgemail" class="valfrm" style='line-height:8px;'></span></td>
          </tr>
         <tr valign="middle">
              <td align="left" class="text-fm" style="padding-top:8px;">
                <b>Mobile No.<font color="#C70017">*</font></b></td>
              <td align="left" class="text-fm">
                <b>:</b></td>
              <td class="text-fm" align="left"> 
                  <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" size="43" maxlength="16" class="inp">
                  <span id="alertMsgphone" class="valfrm" style='line-height:8px;'></span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr valign="middle">
              <td align="left" class="text-fm" style="padding-top:8px;">
                <b>City<font color="#C70017">*</font></b></td>
              <td align="left" class="text-fm">
                <b>:</b></td>
              <td class="text-fm" align="left"> 
               <input type="text" name="city" id="city" size="43" maxlength="76" class="inp">
               <span id="alertMsgCity" class="valfrm" style='line-height:8px;'></span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr valign="middle">
              <td align="left" class="text-fm" style="padding-top:8px;">
                <b>Subject<font color="#C70017">*</font></b></td>
              <td align="left" class="text-fm">
                <b>:</b></td>
              <td class="text-fm" align="left"> 
                  <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" size="43" maxlength="76" class="inp">
                  <span id="alertMsgSubject" class="valfrm" style='line-height:8px;'></span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr valign="middle">
              <td align="left" class="text-fm" style="padding-top:8px;">
                <b>Message<font color="#C70017">*</font></b></td>
              <td align="left" class="text-fm">
                <b>:</b></td>
              <td class="text-fm" align="left"> 
                 <textarea name="message" id="message" size="43" maxlength="16" class="inp" rows="6" cols="30"></textarea>
                 <span id="alertMsgMessage" class="valfrm" style='line-height:8px;'></span></td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
            <td align="left" colspan="3">
              <div align="center"><br>
                <input type="submit" value="" name="Submit" class="imgClass"/>
                <br>
                </td>
          </tr>
              </table>
          </form>
```

Comment: so have you configured your smtp details? please edit your post to show only the relevant code

Comment: i can't put email address and password.

Answer (score 0):

Absence of an error description doesn't imply the absence of an error. Change your error handling code to this:

```
If Err Then
    response.write Err.Number & "<br><br>There was an error on this page."
Else
    response.write "Thank you, your message has been sent."
End If
```

Are you able to connect from your webserver to the mailserver on port 465?

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 465
```

Are you using correct credentials?

Do you have access to the mailserver logs? What do they say about connections from that page? If you don't have access to the actual mailserver, can you set up a dummy server and temporarily point the page to that server, so you can check if the code is working in principle?

Comment: ya i can connect with this port no

Comment: i use correct credentials. with security i'm not putting with code. Email sent successfully to from-address while i'm work with simple form without using onsubmit="return validate();" and javascript.

Comment: Then I'd try simplifying the JavaScript code. What happens when you change change the validation function to `function validate() { return true; }`?